# Call a function from local module in a webworker in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, module, web-worker

So, I encountered a situation where I did not find many valuable resources.
I have a function called `local_module_add_one`; it takes a number and returns its incremented value. This function is part of a module installed locally and that works fine when called in the Angular app in some `test-import.component.ts` file:

```
import { local_module_add_one} from 'my_local_module';
...
test_my_local_module_add_one()
{
  console.log(local_module_add_one(10));
  // Works perfectly fine and displays 11 in the console.
}
```

Now the problem is when I try to call the function `local_module_add_one` using web worker.

I did something like this for the `my-worker.worker.ts` file, similar to the [web-worker documentation](https://angular.io/guide/web-worker):

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
import { local_module_add_one  } from 'my_local_module';

function my_add_one(some_number: number): number {
  return some_number + 1
  };

addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {

  // Does work perfectly fine
  // const response = my_add_one(data.value);

  // ! Does not work
  const response = local_module_add_one(data.value);

  console.log("response of worker: ", response);

  postMessage(response);
});
```

This, unfortunately, did not work.
To make sure that the source of the problem was not a mistake in the way of implementing the web worker. I created the same function in the `my-worker.worker.ts` file, and it works perfectly. Re-writing the function in the local module in *TypeScript* is not a feasible solution in my case.